# SeleniumLib extension throws duplicate keyword name error

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to write Selenium Library extension to ease some things a bit and I've hit a wall. This is my python class:

```
    import uuid
    import time
    import re
    from robot.api.deco import keyword
    from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
    from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary

    class MySeleniumLibrary(SeleniumLibrary):
            # def __init__(self):
            #         BuiltIn().set_library_search_order(self, "SeleniumLibrary")

            @keyword('Select Checkbox')
            def select_checkbox(self, locator):
                    self.wait_until_page_contains_element(locator)
                    elementId = self.get_element_attribute(locator,"id")
                    if elementId=='':
                            elementId = uuid.uuid4()
                            self.assign_id_to_element(locator, elementId)
                    self.execute_javascript('$("#' + elementId + ':not(:checked)").click();')
```

When I run my tests it complaints when building the library:

```
Creating keyword 'Select Checkbox' failed: Keyword with same name defined multiple times.
```

And then it finally fails when trying to select the checkbox:

```
Keyword with same name defined multiple times.
```

I've got only the mySeleniumLibrary.py referenced in my Settings part. I also tried setting the library search order but it didn't work. Have you got any ideas how to achieve this please?

Thank you!

Comment: Suggested reading from the Robot FW user guide: [Creating static keywords, What methods are considered keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#what-methods-are-considered-keywords).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured out a solution how to override SeleniumLibary's inherited method. Trick was removing the specific keyword name on the @keyword line. This is how it looks now:

```
    import uuid
    import time
    import re
    from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
    from SeleniumLibrary.base import keyword
    from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary

    class MySeleniumLibrary(SeleniumLibrary):

            def get_unique_element_id(self, locator):
                    self.wait_until_page_contains_element(locator)
                    elementId = self.get_element_attribute(locator,"id")
                    if elementId=='':
                            elementId = uuid.uuid4()
                            self.assign_id_to_element(locator, elementId)
                    return elementId

            @keyword
            def select_checkbox(self, locator):
                    elementId = self.get_unique_element_id(locator)
                    self.execute_javascript('$("#' + elementId + ':not(:checked)").click();')
```

=> When I call the Select Checkbox keyword now, my method is called instead of the original SeleniumLibrary's one.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary`.

Which Contain `Select Checkbox` Keyword thats why you are getting:

```
Creating keyword 'Select Checkbox' failed: Keyword with same name defined multiple times.
```

You can just change the name of the keyword

```
import uuid
import time
import re
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary


class MySeleniumLibrary(SeleniumLibrary):
    # def __init__(self):
    #         BuiltIn().set_library_search_order(self, "SeleniumLibrary")

    @keyword('Select Checkbox Custom')
    def some_name(self, locator):
        self.wait_until_page_contains_element(locator)
        elementId = self.get_element_attribute(locator, "id")
        if elementId == '':
            elementId = uuid.uuid4()
            self.assign_id_to_element(locator, elementId)
        self.execute_javascript('$("#' + elementId + ':not(:checked)").click();')
```

And then your Robot Framework Test Should be something like

```
*** Settings ***
Library  MySeleniumLibrary.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test Keyword
   Open Browser  hyyp://google.com  chrome
   Select Checkbox Custom  xpath=SomeKidOFXPATHVALUE
```

And this will work as expected.
Note How `Open Browser` keyword works even though I have not referenced the SeleniumLibrary in the settings only the python script, which picks up all the keywords.

For more info on What Methods are considered Keywords Please have a look a this [What Methods are considered Keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#what-methods-are-considered-keywords)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - however I'd like to use the "Select Checkbox" keyword name if possible. Seems like I figured out a way how to do so - by removing the specific keyword name when using @keyword.